# Running java program error "exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Driver"

Tags: java, compilation

I was given a chunk of unfinished code, my assignment is to finish it. However, I was told by my instructor that the original unfinished code should run, yet it does not. I compiled them into .class files, but when I type "java DirectoryLister Driver GUI", I get

```
http://imgur.com/cuN9Ea8
```

I'm totally new to Java, my only prior experience is C. 
I had compiled the three files `GUI.java, directoryLister.java, and Driver.java` together with

```
javac GUI.java DirectoryLister.java Driver.java
```

now I have three .class files in the same directory, but when I do

```
java DirectoryLister Driver GUI
```

I get the error above. Help!

Comment: can you please post the full stack trace

Comment: i have no idea what that means...
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() is on the right track??
but do I just stick that somewhere in my code?

Comment: could you please paste all of error

Comment: To get started in java I recommend The Java Tutorials. Google that.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `java`, you must provide it with *one* class to run, not three.  That class will have its `main` method executed.  You must run `java` from the root directory of where your classes are compiled, and you must use the fully-qualified class name (i.e. including packages).

For example, if you had a source folder `src` with a source file `./a/b/C.java` in it, the class would be compiled in `src/a/b/C.class`.  You would then make sure you're in the `src` and run `java a.b.C`.

Comment: The main method is in the driver.class, and when I "java driver" the same error shows

http://imgur.com/G3fciJw

Comment: @JeffreyShin: All Java identifiers are case sensitive.  If your class is `Driver`, then you need to use `java Driver` not `java driver`.  But it seems like you have another problem.  Can you show the first bit of `Driver`?  It seems like it's declared in package `directoryLister.template`, but you're compiling and running it as if it has no package.  You might need to put it at path `directoryLister/template/Driver.java` and run it with `java directoryLister.template.Driver`.

Comment: http://imgur.com/7eQQHLm

Comment: After reading the post below, I understood what you meant by your post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From these errors it looks like it's a package issue.

First, You can't run `java` on multiple files as java will pass the latter names as command-line arguments.

Second, at the top of DirectoryLister.java you should see

```
package directoryLister.template;
```

This means the ***Fully Qualified Name*** of the java class is `directoryLister.template.DirectoryLister`. The fully qualified name is basically the full class name, including the package it resides in. Packages are groupings of classes in the same directory on the filesystem.

The way java is set up, a java source file can be compiled from any working directory. However, running `java` on a class file is very strict:

- If the source file is in the package foo.bar, the directory the class file is located in must be called foo/bar/.
- `java` must be run from the root of the package hierarchy. If a class file is located in myjavafiles/foo/bar/, and is in package foo.bar, you must have myjavafiles as your current working directory when running java.
- Java must be passed the fully qualified name of the class, as two classes can have the same name if they are in different packages. This means you must run `java directoryLister.template.DirectoryLister` or whatever class contains your main class.
- Note the periods in the above statement, not slashes. `javac`, however, requires slashes.
- Note that java will find the other class files as long as they're in the right spot, you don't have to pass them as arguments to `java`.
- Also note that `javac` doesn't have these strict restrictions as `java`.

[See here for more info on Fully Qualified names.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7)